# Troubleshooting Hot-Reload Issues in Angular Project After Upgrading from Version 15 to 17

Tags: angular, hot-reload, angular17

I am experiencing a problem with hot-reloading in my Angular project. I recently upgraded it from version 15 to 17. Now, when I make changes to my code, I have to run `ng build` followed by `ng serve` to see the latest updates. However, I expect to see the latest changes without having to run `ng build`. It's very cumbersome to do this for every code change.

In my `angular.json`, I have the following configuration:

```json
"build": {
   "development": {
      "aot": false
   }
},
"serve": {
    "configurations": {
       "development": {
          "liveReload": true
       }
    }
}
```

package.json:

```json
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng serve --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
```

The methods I've tried so far include:

- Removing `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`, then running `npm install`.
- Reloading the browser with 'Ctrl + F5'.

How can solve this problem?

Comment: Looks like related to https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/26565

Comment: I changed 'watch' from 'scripts' to "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development". Now it works well when I run 'npm run watch'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually removing `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`, you should have run `npm ci` to perform a clean install. This command requires both `package.json` and `package-lock.json` and automatically removes `node_modules` if present. It also does not install newer package versions like `npm install`. Check out [npm-ci](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-ci) for more information.

When encountering issues related to the Angular development server, you should restart it first. If unsuccessful, you can try to run `ng cache clean`.

I don't see anything wrong with your configuration. Also note by default, `ng build` compiles a production version of your Angular app in the `dist` folder which is not what you want here.